# Javascript: given list of functions, how to create an object having those functions as properties?

Tags: javascript

Given:

```
var f1 = function(){return "a";};
var f2 = function(){return "b";};
var f3 = function(){return "c";};
transformToObject([f1, f2, f3]);
```

How can I create a function:

```
function transformToObject(arrayOfFuncs){...};
```

which returns:

```
{
    f1: function(){return "a";},
    f2: function(){return "b";},
    f3: function(){return "c";}
}
```

The difficulty seems to get the name of the variable to create a property of the object.

Notice: since I define functions in the form of assignment of anonymous functions to variables, the "name" property of functions won't help because it's empty,
which means:

```
function a(){};
//a.name === "a"
var b = function(){};
//b.name === ""
```

Comment: You cannot. Just write it as an object literal right away.

Comment: And notice that you cannot rely on `.name` anyway, it's a non-standard property and not supported in many browsers.

Answer (score 3):

```
var f1 = function(){return "a";};
var f2 = function(){return "b";};
var f3 = function(){return "c";};

var obj = {f1: f1, f2: f2, f3: f3};

alert(obj.f1());
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7rbYd/1/)

As per your edit, perhaps something like this:

```
var f1 = function(){return "a";};
var f2 = function(){return "b";};
var f3 = function(){return "c";};

function transformToObject(){
    return {f1: f1, f2: f2, f3: f3};
}

var myObjectHasFunctions = transformToObject();

alert(myObjectHasFunctions.f1());
```

[**Demo2**](http://jsfiddle.net/7rbYd/4/)

Or something really wild:

```
var f1 = function a(){return "a";};
var f2 = function b(){return "b";};
var f3 = function c(){return "c";};

var arrayOfFuncs = [f1, f2, f3]

function transformToObject(arrayOfFuncs){
    var obj = {}
    obj.functions = []

    arrayOfFuncs.forEach(function(test){
        obj.functions.push({name: test.name, method: test})
    });

    return obj;
}

var myObjectHasFunctions = transformToObject(arrayOfFuncs);

myObjectHasFunctions.functions.forEach(function(func){
    alert(func.method());    
});
```

[**Demo3**](http://jsfiddle.net/7rbYd/6/)

But you're really best off doing something like (2) as mentioned in the various comments.

Comment: I apologize :/, I meant to ask something a bit different. I corrected the question. I want to pass the functions to an external function to create the object, and my whole point is to avoid this type of code which I do use currently. Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: I've added that example now too.  The general structure should be the same.  Adjust to whatever you need?

Comment: OK, maybe it's again my bad for not being clear... :) The point is to make it a generic function, which sits in an external file. So I pass an array of any functions.

Comment: You need a way of discerning the name of the functions in order to call them on the object, so you'd still be best in making an object containing functions and their names instead of an array of functions without names.

Answer (score 0):

It is *kind of* possible by looking through the properties of the global scope for the matching values:

```
var transformToObject = (function(scope){
  return function(arrayOfFuncs){
    var obj = {};
    for(var prop in scope){
      if(scope.hasOwnProperty(prop) && arrayOfFuncs.indexOf(scope[prop]) > -1){
        obj[prop] = scope[prop]
      }
    }
    return obj
  }
})(this)
```

… though this is a really bad thing to do

If possible - you'd be better modifying your function to be something like:

```
transformToObject(['fn1','fn2','fn3']);
```

Better still, have the functions as properties of an object from the start.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you should just create the object initially, instead of the array. 
But if you just want to assign arbitrary function names, you can do something like this:

```
function transformToObject(arrayOfFuncs){
  var len = arrayOfFuncs.length,
      functionMap = {},
      funcName;
  for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
    funcName = "f" + i;
    functionMap[funcName] = arrayOfFuncs[i];
  }
  return functionMap;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that the names of functions are lost in Your code, and so cannot be recovered. You **need** to supply them somehow.

if You know them ahead and can put in an array, then Your code would simply be:

```
function transformToObject(fns, names) {
  var r = {};
  for (var i = 0, n = fns.length; i < n; ++i) r[names[i]] = fns[i];
  return r;
}
```

if You had a function which would return a name given a function:

```
function transformToObject(fns, namer) {
  var r = {}
  for (var i = 0, n = fns.length; i < n; ++i) r[namer(fns[i])] = fns[i]
  return r;
}
```

**EDIT:** CUT :)

Comment: No need to even use .toString or extract its name to get the source code and the name.  Take a look at my third example above at how I'm accessing those.

Comment: Oh, great, didn't know about .name property. :)

Comment: Oh, Max says functions are declared nameless, so .name is of no use, unluckily.